# Swift: Take a screenshot of the viewController and share it on Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift3

I created the following function to share a post on Facebook:

```
@IBAction func socialShare(_ sender: Any){
    //Alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Share", message: "First share!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    //First action
    let actionOne = UIAlertAction(title: "Share on Facebook", style: .default) { (action) in

        //Checking if user is connected to Facebook
        if SLComposeViewController.isAvailable(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        {
            let post = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)!
            post.setInitialText("First")
            post.add(UIImage(named: "Mylogo.png"))
            self.present(post, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {self.showAlert(service: "Facebook")}
    }

    let actionThree = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    //Add action to action sheet
    alert.addAction(actionOne)
    alert.addAction(actionThree)

    //Present alert
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)    
}

func showAlert(service:String){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You are not connected to \(service)", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But what I really want to do is to share an image and this image must be a screenshot of the viewController in which the user taps the share button. Is this possible? If so, how?

**Update:**

For the screenshot I have found a function like this:

```
func screenShotMethod() {
    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

But I don't know how to implement it in my code.

Comment: Probably you should describe little bit better what is your problem.
The second piece of code is creating UIImage in the "image" variable. And you just have to use it instead of "UIImage(named: "Mylogo.png")". 
But I'm not sure this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do that you can do something like this

```
func screenShotMethod() -> UIImage? {
    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

And add it to:

```
    let post = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)!
    post.setInitialText("First")
    post.add(screenShotMethod())
    self.present(post, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: `screenShotMethod()` returns an optional image, better use guard or if let

Comment: Sure! but post.add method accept optional values, isn't it?